# Return a string with swapping every element[0] by element[1] in a string

Tags: javascript

I want to swap element `0` by element `1` so element `1` become `0` idx and element `0` become `1` idx.
 for instance `Hello guys` becomes `eHllo ugys`
my code is kind of tedious and it returns something like this `eHll ougys` it moves the last letter of a word to the first letter of the next word.
is there a way to do it without forloop?.

```js
const tex = `Hello guys`;
const swap = str => {
  let swapped = [];
   strin = str.split('');
  for (let i = 0; i < strin.length; i++) { 
    if (i < strin.length) {
      swapped[i] = strin[i + 1];
      swapped[i + 1] = strin[i];
      i += 1;
    } else {
      swapped[i] = strin[i];
    }
  }
  return swapped.join('');
}
console.log(swap(tex));
```

Comment: Shouldn't `Hello guys` become `eHllo ugsy`, swapping the "y" and the "s" at the very end too?

Comment: @CertainPerformance No, just idx 0 and idx 1

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use a regular expression - capture one word character at the beginning of a word followed by another captured word character, and replace with those swapped capture groups:

```js
const tex = `Hello guys`;
const Swap = str => str.replace(/\b(\w)(\w)/g, '$2$1');
console.log(Swap(tex));
```

Answer (score 2):

This alternative splits the string by space.

Then, using the array, the function `map` converts the strings into the desired output.

```js
let swap = s =>
  s.split(/\s/).map(s => {
    let split = s.split(''),
      letters = [];

    if (split.length > 1) { // This is for string with only one char
      // Get the two chars -> He
      // reverse them -> eH
      letters = split.splice(0, 2).reverse();
    }

    return letters.join('') + split.join('');
  }).join(' ');

console.log(swap("Hello guys"));
console.log(swap("Ele From S"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it using split and join (without any regex):

```js
const tex = `Hello guys`;
const strs = tex.split(' ')
const changed = strs.map(str => {
  const s = str.split('')
  const s1 = s[1]
  const s0 = s[0]
  s[0] = s1
  s[1] = s0
  return s.join('')
})

console.log(changed.join(' '))
```